# How to change the scale between ticks

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Is it possible to change the spacing between two ticks?

4000-3000 = 3000-2000 = 2000-1500 = 1500-1000

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=16cm,
    height=6cm,
    xmin=400, xmax=4000,
    x dir= reverse,
    ymin=40,ymax=105,
    tickpos=left,
    xtick={500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000},
    enlargelimits=false,
    ytick align=outside,
    xtick align=outside
]

\nextgroupplot
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data1.dat};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data2.dat};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Example:

[image]

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=2 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
    },
    height=5cm,
    x dir= reverse,
    ymin=35,ymax=105,
    tickpos=left,
    xtick align=outside
]
\nextgroupplot [xmin=2000.1, xmax=4000, width=6.9cm,ytick align=outside,axis y line*=left,xtick={3000,4000}]
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data1.dat};
\nextgroupplot [ytick=\empty,xmin=400, xmax=2000.1, width=10cm,axis y line*=right, xtick={500,1000,1500,2000}]
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data1.dat};
\nextgroupplot [xmin=2000.1, xmax=4000, width=6.9cm,ytick align=outside,axis y     line*=left,xtick={3000,4000}]
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data2.dat};
\nextgroupplot [ytick=\empty,xmin=400, xmax=2000.1, width=10cm,axis y line*=right,    xtick={500,1000,1500,2000}]
\addplot [smooth, black, no marks] file {data2.dat};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Not good but it works. If there is an easier Solution tell me please.

Comment: your screenshot looks like it was plotted with the `semilogx`. To get linear scale, don't use `semilogx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot spectrometer output in this format, which is [apparently something of a  standard](http://books.google.ca/books?id=huf1ABN313IC&pg=PA86), you can use a coordinate transform. If you set

```
x coord trafo/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{#1-0.5*(#1-2000)*(#1>2000)}
}
```

the x unit distance above 2000 is halved. To get correct tick labels, you also need to define the inverse transform:

```
x coord inv trafo/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{#1+(#1-2000)*(#1>2000)}
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=16cm,
    height=6cm,
    xmin=500, xmax=4000,
    x dir= reverse,
    ymin=40,ymax=105,
    tickpos=left,
    x coord trafo/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1-0.5*(#1-2000)*(#1>2000)}
    },
    x coord inv trafo/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1+(#1-2000)*(#1>2000)}
    },
    xtick={500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000},
    enlargelimits=false,
    ytick align=outside,
    xtick align=outside,
    domain=500:4000, samples=100
]

\nextgroupplot
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\addplot [smooth] {(x<2000)*rnd*50+40+rnd*5};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [smooth] {(x<2000)*rnd*50+40+rnd*5};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```