# A stretch function for particular domain using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have plot that depicts values over 24h. >95% of the data is in the `y \in [1,10]` domain, so I'd like to decrease grid rectangle size by, say, half. Rough example of what I'd like the ticks to become after 10- [image: exampleUno].

I know I can transform the coordinates (you'll see it commented out), but that doesn't change the tick distance, something that would give the illusion of zooming out of the grid to see more of the points in a sparsely populated region of the graph, and that'd save v-space.

Flipping through the `pgfplots` documentation, I'm unsure this is possible normally. I'm open to anything from other packages, as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.8cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=18.5cm,
    height=9cm,%6.8cm
    compat=1.15,
    every axis/.append style={
        line width=1pt,
        tick style={line width=0.8pt}},
    colormap={cm}{color(0)=(blue!75) color(2.8)=(green) color(5.5)=(orange) color(16)=(red)},%
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            tick align=outside,
            date coordinates in=x,
            table/col sep=comma,
            xticklabel={\hour},
            xlabel={Feb 2018},
            xmin=2018-02-01 23:45,
            xmax=2018-02-03 00:15,
            xtick distance= 0.04167,% 1/24, unit is hours
            % y coord trafo/.code={
            %   \pgfmathparse{#1-0.5*(#1-10)*(#1>10)}},
            % y coord inv trafo/.code={
            %    \pgfmathparse{#1+(#1-10)*(#1>10)}},
            ymin=1,%ymax=17.25,
            yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
            ylabel={...},
            ytick distance=1,
            grid=both,
        ]
    \addplot [
        only marks, 
        scatter,
    ] table [x index=0,y index=1] {
    2018-02-02 11:18, 2.7
    2018-02-02 14:52, 3.7
    2018-02-02 18:05, 4.1
    2018-02-02 06:00, 6.8
    2018-02-02 13:32, 5.0
    2018-02-02 17:38, 2.4
    2018-02-02 22:49, 4.7
    2018-02-02 00:05, 2.7
    2018-02-02 03:02, 5.2
    2018-02-02 12:47, 8.5
    2018-02-02 16:00, 3.2
    2018-02-02 17:54, 5.8
    2018-02-02 19:47, 5.5
    2018-02-02 01:01, 5.5
    2018-02-02 14:49, 8.4
    2018-02-02 16:26, 6.1
    2018-02-02 18:17, 3.7
    2018-02-02 02:08, 4.9
    2018-02-02 04:52, 2.4
    2018-02-02 13:45, 4.4
    2018-02-02 17:06, 2
    2018-02-02 18:27, 5.0
    2018-02-02 01:55, 3.4
    2018-02-02 12:38, 4.7
    2018-02-02 15:08, 6.2
    2018-02-02 20:56, 6.2
    2018-02-02 06:04, 2.6
    2018-02-02 15:52, 3.2
    2018-02-02 17:57, 2.8
    2018-02-02 21:05, 2.8
    2018-02-02 22:20, 3.1
    2018-02-02 00:06, 3.3
    2018-02-02 01:18, 11.4
    2018-02-02 05:56, 2.2
    2018-02-02 13:38, 3.6
    2018-02-02 16:49, 2.2
    2018-02-02 21:02, 5.3
    2018-02-02 01:08, 2.2
    2018-02-02 13:46, 3.4
    2018-02-02 17:46, 4.0
    2018-02-02 22:28, 2.8
    2018-02-02 05:38, 12.4
    2018-02-02 14:35, 3.6
    2018-02-02 17:41, 3.2
    2018-02-02 03:17, 2.4
    2018-02-02 08:39, 5.7
    2018-02-02 12:36, 10.0
    2018-02-02 13:41, 6.2
    2018-02-02 20:15, 4.6
    2018-02-02 01:57, 6.3
    2018-02-02 03:35, 3.2
    2018-02-02 04:29, 2.9
    2018-02-02 13:06, 7.3
    2018-02-02 17:55, 3.4
    2018-02-02 21:43, 2.6
    2018-02-02 23:58, 4.2
    2018-02-02 04:28, 2.1
    2018-02-02 15:14, 11.7
    };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: I probably continue to misinterpret your question, but one of the problems is that the screenshot has much more data than your MWE. First question: are you happy with the transformations provided by `y coord trafo`? If so, do you want additional magenta grid lines?

Comment: @marmot I know there's a character limit, didn't want to reach with useless coordinates, the 50 given are a part of the normal one, and have 3 or 4 outliers to illustrate the situation.
The `coord (inv) trafo` are fine, I kind of learned how to use them here- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119300/how-to-change-the-scale-between-ticks 

Magenta shows how I want the grid above y=10 to look like (not color-wise), tick size shrunk to half. Re: your answer- I want that look, but 10,12,14,16.. instead of 10,11,12,13 ..

Comment: I see. I revised my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps now I am guessing correctly what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.8cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=18.5cm,
    height=9cm,%6.8cm
    compat=1.15,
    every axis/.append style={
        line width=1pt,
        tick style={line width=0.8pt}},
    colormap={cm}{color(0)=(blue!75) color(2.8)=(green) color(5.5)=(orange) color(16)=(red)},%
    }
\begin{document}
\def\mya{0.75}
You are making a stretch transformation
\[ y~\mapsto~y'~=~y-a\,\Theta(y-10)\cdot (y-10)\]
in order to stretch the points above 10. $\Theta$ denotes the usual Heaviside
function. The inverse transformation is given by
\[ y(y')~=~y'+\frac{a}{1-a}\Theta(y'-10)\cdot (y'-10)\;.\]
If you want the stretching to be more pronounced, choose $a$ closer to 1. Here I
am going to take it to be $a=\mya$.
\begin{figure}[hb]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            tick align=outside,
            date coordinates in=x,
            table/col sep=comma,
            xticklabel={\hour},
            xlabel={Feb 2018},
            xmin=2018-02-01 23:45,
            xmax=2018-02-03 00:15,
            xtick distance= 0.04167,% 1/24, unit is hours
            y coord trafo/.code={
              \pgfmathparse{#1-\mya*(#1-10)*(#1>10)}},
            y coord inv trafo/.code={
               \pgfmathparse{#1+(\mya/(1-\mya))*(#1-10)*(#1>10)}},
            ymin=1,%ymax=17.25,
            extra y ticks={11,12,13},
            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=11
            \else
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=13
            \else
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}
            \fi
            \fi
            },
            %yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(ifthenelse(\tick<10.5,\tick,10+2*(\tick-10)))}\pgfmathresult},
            ylabel={...},
            ytick distance=1,
            grid=both,
        ]
    \addplot+[
        only marks, 
        scatter,
    ] table [x index=0,y index=1] {
    2018-02-02 11:18, 2.7
    2018-02-02 14:52, 3.7
    2018-02-02 18:05, 4.1
    2018-02-02 06:00, 6.8
    2018-02-02 13:32, 5.0
    2018-02-02 17:38, 2.4
    2018-02-02 22:49, 4.7
    2018-02-02 00:05, 2.7
    2018-02-02 03:02, 5.2
    2018-02-02 12:47, 8.5
    2018-02-02 16:00, 3.2
    2018-02-02 17:54, 5.8
    2018-02-02 19:47, 5.5
    2018-02-02 01:01, 5.5
    2018-02-02 14:49, 8.4
    2018-02-02 16:26, 6.1
    2018-02-02 18:17, 3.7
    2018-02-02 02:08, 4.9
    2018-02-02 04:52, 2.4
    2018-02-02 13:45, 4.4
    2018-02-02 17:06, 2
    2018-02-02 18:27, 5.0
    2018-02-02 01:55, 3.4
    2018-02-02 12:38, 4.7
    2018-02-02 15:08, 6.2
    2018-02-02 20:56, 6.2
    2018-02-02 06:04, 2.6
    2018-02-02 15:52, 3.2
    2018-02-02 17:57, 2.8
    2018-02-02 21:05, 2.8
    2018-02-02 22:20, 3.1
    2018-02-02 00:06, 3.3
    2018-02-02 01:18, 11.4
    2018-02-02 05:56, 2.2
    2018-02-02 13:38, 3.6
    2018-02-02 16:49, 2.2
    2018-02-02 21:02, 5.3
    2018-02-02 01:08, 2.2
    2018-02-02 13:46, 3.4
    2018-02-02 17:46, 4.0
    2018-02-02 22:28, 2.8
    2018-02-02 05:38, 12.4
    2018-02-02 14:35, 3.6
    2018-02-02 17:41, 3.2
    2018-02-02 03:17, 2.4
    2018-02-02 08:39, 5.7
    2018-02-02 12:36, 10.0
    2018-02-02 13:41, 6.2
    2018-02-02 20:15, 4.6
    2018-02-02 01:57, 6.3
    2018-02-02 03:35, 3.2
    2018-02-02 04:29, 2.9
    2018-02-02 13:06, 7.3
    2018-02-02 17:55, 3.4
    2018-02-02 21:43, 2.6
    2018-02-02 23:58, 4.2
    2018-02-02 04:28, 2.1
    2018-02-02 15:14, 11.7
    };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Making it an answer was a mistake, sorry. The four highest values 10.0, 11.4, 12.4, 11.7 are interpreted as 10.0 exactly, and the rest above 12. So something is wrong, however, doing a transformation of the yticklabels above 10 is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @vlg I do not understand your comment. What do you mean by "The four highest values 10.0, 11.4, 12.4, 11.7 are interpreted as 10.0 exactly"? The four highest dots clearly have different y-positions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the value of 10.0 stays the same, because the function occurs only for values >10. However, the three other values I noted, get transformed into ones of higher value, specifically they're over the 12 y grid line.

Comment: @vlg I am sorry, I really do not understand the statements you make. What does "the value of 10.0 stays the same, because the function occurs only for values >10" mean? (Of course, the modification is such that only the ticks above 10 get "faked" but I thought that this is what you want.) What precisely should happen to the points with y values greater (or equal) 10 and what should happen to the ticks with such values?

Comment: re:function- p.927 of pgfmanual.pdf (=1 if T, =0 if F) as used in my example). I want accurate date points to be represented everywhere, values above 10 should pushed down the same amount as the ticks above 10 get pushed down, squashed, or lowered. A tighter grid above y=10, with more grid lines, but less vertical space; y values of 10.0 should stay on the line. Ticks have to match the data.

Comment: I don't understand why y-data and y-ticks >10 don't get treated the same way when they have identical function. The one by @marmot seems different from the y transformation offered so I'm fiddling with            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(ifthenelse(\tick<10,\tick,\tick-0.5*(\tick-10)))}\pgfmathresult},% but still, I can't get the points where they need to be.

Comment: @vlg I didn't know that you were referring to the Theta-function, please see my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75012/discussion-between-vlg-and-marmot).